# How to call url with multiple query string params in FeignClient?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, feign

I try to call Google API with multiple query string parameters. And curiously, I can't find a way to do that.

This is my FeignClient :

```
@FeignClient(name="googleMatrix", url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json")
public interface GoogleMatrixClient {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="?key={key}&origins={origins}&destinations={destinations}")
    GoogleMatrixResult process(@PathVariable(value="key") String key,
                               @PathVariable(value="origins") String origins,
                               @PathVariable(value="destinations") String destinations);

}
```

The problem is that '&' character of the `RequestMapping value` is replace by `&amp;`

How to avoid this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 33, accepted):

All Query parameters will automatically be extracted from the url by a split using the `&` character and mapped to the corresponding `@RequestParam` in the method declaration.

So you don't need to specify all the keys the `@RequestMapping` annotation and there you should only specify the endpoint value.

For your example to work you just need to change your rest-endpoint to:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
GoogleMatrixResult process(@RequestParam(value="key") String key,
                           @RequestParam(value="origins") String origins,
                           @RequestParam(value="destinations") String destin);
```

Comment: Ok, perfect, I test a lot of things but not this !

Comment: Took me a few hours to realize that spring boot requires openfeign 9.7.0, not 10.0.1 (otherwise you get an error about missing function in jar)

Answer (score -11):

**use this:-

```
 RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/test/{key}/{origins}/{destinations}")
        GoogleMatrixResult process(@PathVariable("key") String key,
                                   @PathVariable("origins") String origins,
                                   @PathVariable("destinations") String destinations);
```

then form url
say:-
http://localhost:portnumber/.../key-value/origins-value/destinations-value
and hit this url, I am sure it will work for you using @PathVariable annotations**