# netflix feign issue with query parameters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, netflix-feign

I am using feign client for some discovery and request.

I am using query parameter in my request

if I hard code like below it works.

```
@FeignClient("userdetailservice")
public interface UserServiceClient {
@RequestMapping(
            method= RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "/alluser/getmyuser?user=1234")
    String getUserDetails();
    }
```

But this one does not work, it sending request as 'POST' though I mentioned as GET.  Its very strange.

```
@FeignClient("userdetailservice")
public interface UserServiceClient {
@RequestMapping(
            method= RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "/alluser/getmyuser?user={userid}")
    String getUserDetails(@Param(value = "userid") String userid);
    }
```

So how to send a query parameters in Feign request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Query parameters will automatically be extracted from the url by a split using the `&` character and mapped to the corresponding `@RequestParam` in the method declaration.

So you don't need to specify all the keys the `@RequestMapping` annotation and there you should only specify the endpoint value.

You can check the answer in the following question :

- [How to call url with multiple query string params in FeignClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970498/how-to-call-url-with-multiple-query-string-params-in-feignclient/40970663)